# Oracle Select Query based on Column value

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, duplicates

I have two tables lets say

```
Table A
```

**columns** `id , name address`

```
Table B
```

**columns** `id , age, import_date`

The `Table B id` is a reference key of `Table A.`

Now I want to return results from `A & B b`ut if the record is not in B I still want to see the record so for this I use left outer join

```
Select * from A a left join B b
on a.id = b.id
```

Now even I don't have record in B I still get the record.

Table B may contain duplicate ids but unique import_date.

Now I want to results in a way that if there is duplicate id in table B then I want to get the records only where i`mport_date` is as of today.

I still want to get the records for ids which are not there but if the ID is there in table B then I want to apply above condition.

I hope someone can help me with this.

***Sample data***

```
Table A

01|John|London
02|Matt|Glasgow
03|Rodger|Paris

Table B

02|22|31-AUG-2015
02|21|30-AUG-2015
02|23|29-AUG-2015
```

The query will return

```
01|John|London|null|null|null
02|Matt|Glasgow|22|31-Aug-2015
03|Rodger|Paris|null|null
```

Comment: Select * from A a left join B b on
a.id = b.id

Comment: @Tarun I already have that query. I had a typo which I've fixed.

Comment: Post some sample data and required output.

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @Crazy2crack Its Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got the solution. Just add one more condition like below

```
Select a.id,a.name,a.address,b.age,b.import_date 
       from tablea a left join tableb b 
            on a.id=b.id and b.import_date=trunc(sysdate)
            order by a.id;---This line optional
```

Check the [**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07e2a/12)

Comment: If I have understood your query correctly,even if some rows with an updated date like 01-SEP-2015 is added to the table, your query would display the one with the date 31-AUG-2015. Am I correct??

Comment: b.import_date = CURDATE() - This edit will select only current date

Comment: Thanks guys.I didn't notice that requirement. But `Curdate()` is in MYSQL. Oracle equivalent is `sysdate`. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_A t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B t2 ON t1.id=t2.id UNION
SELECT * 
FROM Table_A t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
GROUP BY t2.import_date
HAVING t2.import_date=CURDATE();
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to add some explanation of what this does and why it solves the problem?